# Mouseenter continues to run even with the mouse being outside the div

Tags: jquery

I have a div that moves randomly. If you put the mouse on it, the mouseenter works perfectly. The problem is that the mouseenter continues to run even when the div moves out of the mouse.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6rqzhaqo/ 
(place your mouse over the red box and let it stop, the 'X' continues to appear)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv(); 
});
  $('.a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
       self.append('X');
    }, 25);
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});


function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1]}, 1000, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    
};
```

```css
div.a {
width: 200px;
height:50px;
 background-color:red;
position:fixed;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='a'></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something wrong in your code, it's browser bug, the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` will only trigger when mouse moving, if your mouse stays and the element moves, the events will not trigger even it should.

So in your case, the `mouseenter` is not working properly too, you can try it by stay your mouse at some place, wait the moving div hit your pointer, you can see nothing happens.

The solution I know is to track mouse coordinates and check in the animation function to simulate mouse enter/leave events.

I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rqzhaqo/2/

There are something you must be careful:

1. You have to use interval to simulate event binding, you can't use body event 
   because the event will not trigger if you don't move mouse, you can't use animate event, because it will only trigger once after animate is finish.
2. The flag is necessary, because without flag, the simulate event will keep trigger, you only need once.
3. You have to bind a `mousemove` event to body, in order to get mouse position in time, because there is no way to get mouse position without event.

Comment: Thank you! How can i do it?

Comment: Basically, set a flag to identify if the mouse is in div first,you need to get mouse coordinates in animate function, and compare the coordinates with current div position, you can calculate the left top of div and right bottom of div, if the mouse coordinates in this range and the flag is false(means the mouse is not in div before), set the flag true, and trigger your own mouseenter function. Same as mouseleave part.

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: no, the only right thing is check position part. see my update.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the example.